# Continuing after an interrupted charge

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, charge, reach

Assume the following positions [with A being char 1 (with a non-reach weapon) and B being char 2 with a reach weapon and X being empty squares]:

A X1 X2 B

It's A's turn, he charges (which he can as he's >10 ft away), but B gets an Attack of Opportunity (AoO) as A attempts to leave X1 and as his attack-roll beats his CMD he manages to trip A.

Does this mean A's turn is over (besides any free or swift actions) or can he "recycle" the components of the charge action, for example into a move action to get back up, or to crawl next to B (either of which of course provoke AoO again, if B has Combat Reflexes or such)?

---

Info from a related [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35960/can-you-interrupt-an-action-with-a-ready-action) - here in the comments it's claimed that A would get to continue differently, but the SRD quote "Assuming he is still capable of doing so, he continues his actions once you complete your readied action." just talks of continuing his actions, not that he gets to change them, and laying on the ground he wouldn't be able to "continue his actions", as his actions were a charge, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Charge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Charge)ing is a [Full-Round Action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Trip). Full-Round Actions cannot be combined with Move or Standard Actions. Thus, when A is tripped, A doesn't have any Standard or Move Actions to use. Thus, A's turn is functionally over (free/swift actions, hero points, etc. notwithstanding).

The "charge as a Standard Action" clause of [charge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Charge) doesn't trigger, as A isn't restricted to a Standard Action (and, is too close to charge, anyway).

Thus, the order of actions is:

- A declares that she is [charge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Charge)ing

  - A is declaring that they are using a [Full Round Action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Full-Round-Actions) to do so; thus, they have no Standard or Move actions left this turn
- A moves to X1
- A exits X1 to enter X2, provoking an [Attack of Opportunity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity)
- B chooses to take the AoO, and successfully [trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Trip)s A
- A falls prone in X1
- A's turn is over (barring free/swift actions and such)

Note that, if A had chosen to simply walk up to (as a Move Action) B and then attack (as a Standard Action), A would still have a Standard Action to do with what they pleased. This is part of the trade-off for charging.