# Can Bloody Counter invalidate an attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spheres-of-might

In Spheres Of Might one of the Berserker talents is

> Bloody Counter
> As an immediate action, when a creature targets you with
> a melee attack, before the attack roll is made you may allow
> the attack to automatically strike you (although the roll is still
> made to determine if the attack threatens a critical hit). After
> the damage is determined, you may make a brutal strike targeting that creature as a free action that may be taken even when
> it isn’t your turn, if it is in range. If the creature attacking you
> is battered, you may resolve your attack action prior to their
> attack being resolved.

If your attack kills them or pushes them out of their weapons range does it invalidate any damage they would have dealt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### If your target is *battered*, yes

The text establishes that the enemy attack concludes before your return attack; however, in the case that the target is battered, **your attack is resolved first**. In any case where an action is no longer valid, it is interrupted. Because the ability is phrased such that the action is already commited to "targets you with a melee attack", the action is also lost (although I have seen GM's rule, a la targetting spells, that if there is another valid target in their new range after an interrupt, they can decide to pivot and attack them instead).

See [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/35961/28326) to a related question for the full details on action interruption outlined in the [FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9rb0).

> If an AoO or other interrupting effect reduces what actions I can take on my turn, does this reduction apply immediately?
>
> Yes, even if it interrupts **or limits** your in-progress.

Comment: RE: "In **any case** where an action is no longer valid, it is interrupted" (emphasis mine). Can this be sourced?

Comment: "Can this be sourced?" It's sourced in the link provided by Ifusaso. It's also in this FAQ: https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9rb0

Comment: @Theaitetos The FAQ's saying, "If you somehow impose a limitation on a creature's actions in the middle of that creature's actions, that limitation applies immediately." The FAQ doesn't say anything about, for instance, interrupting with a Ready action, which can render the action that triggered it invalid yet still leave the creature with its full complement of actions. (My issue was with the scope of that statement, hence the emphasis on *any case.*.)

Comment: I would call leaving them with no valid target a limitation on their actions, personally. I could see that as a bit pedantic, but there is *no other precedent* that I'm aware of, so I extrapolate from the closest fitting rules.